# how to do multiple text highlight in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
import React from "react";

function App() {
  const highlightMatchingText = (text, matchingText, secondMatch) => {
    

    const matchRegex = RegExp(matchingText, "ig");

    // Matches array needed to maintain the correct letter casing
    const matches = [...text.matchAll(matchRegex)];
    matches.push([secondMatch]);
    console.log(matches);
    return text.split(matchRegex).map((nonBoldText, index, arr) => (
      <React.Fragment key={index}>
        {nonBoldText}
        {index + 1 !== arr.length && <mark>{matches[index]}</mark>}
      </React.Fragment>
    ));
  };
  return (
    <p>
      {highlightMatchingText(
        "The aim of this study was to determine in vitro the potential of Aloe Vera juice as a skin permeation enhancer; a secondary aim was to probe the extent to which Aloe Vera itself permeates the skin. Saturated solutions of caffeine, colchicine, mefenamic acid, oxybutynin, and quinine were prepared at 32 degrees C in Aloe Vera juice and water (control) and used to dose porcine ear skin",

        "Aloe Vera",
        "skin"
      )}
    </p>
  );
}

export default App;
```

if I pass the multiple different  keywords as args  I need to highlight the in the text, but it is working in only one keyword (one argument ) plz help me how to fix it, "Aloe Vera", is working but "skin" is not working

"

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-benz-gqf11i?file=/src/App.js:0-1142

Answer (score 1):

I changed the `matchingText` to an array in which you can place all the text you want to match. Then in the `RegExp` we joint `textToMatch` with an `|`. This will match "Aloe Vera" OR "skin".

```js
function App() {
  const highlightMatchingText = (text, textToMatch) => {
    let matching;

    const matchRegex = RegExp(textToMatch.join('|'), "ig");

    // Matches array needed to maintain the correct letter casing
    const matches = [...text.matchAll(matchRegex)];
    console.log(matches);
    return text.split(matchRegex).map((nonBoldText, index, arr) => (
      <React.Fragment key={index}>
        {nonBoldText}
        {index + 1 !== arr.length && <mark>{matches[index]}</mark>}
      </React.Fragment>
    ));
  };
  return (
    <p>
      {highlightMatchingText(
        "The aim of this study was to determine in vitro the potential of Aloe Vera juice as a skin permeation enhancer; a secondary aim was to probe the extent to which Aloe Vera itself permeates the skin. Saturated solutions of caffeine, colchicine, mefenamic acid, oxybutynin, and quinine were prepared at 32 degrees C in Aloe Vera juice and water (control) and used to dose porcine ear skin",
        ["Aloe Vera", "skin"]
      )}
    </p>
  );
}
```

Check here the [live version](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-ptolemy-csuh5n)

Hope this helps you with your project!

Answer (score 1):

try this：[react-multi-highlight](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-highlight)

react component to highlight multiple words in text according to each config

```
import Highlighter from 'react-multi-highlight';

export default () => (
  <Highlighter
    config={[
      {
        word: 'and',
        className: 'a',
        style: {
          color: 'blue',
        },
      },
      {
        word: 'nd light-off tim',
        className: 'c',
        style: {
          textDecoration: 'underline',
          textDecorationColor: 'green',
        },
      },
    ]}
    highlightTag="span"
    normalTag="span"
    text="Life, thin and light-off time and time again"
  />
);
```